# Can this Python script be improved?

Tags: python, yield

Can this Python code be improved?

```
   def build_list(types):
        for x in types:
            for a in ['short', 'long', 'average']:
                for b in ['square', 'sloped', 'average']:
                    for c in ['small', 'large', 'average']:
                        for d in ['thin', 'thick', 'average']:
                            for e in ['high', 'low', 'average']:
                                for f in [True, False]:
                                    for g in [True, False]:
                                        for h in ['flat', 'thick', 'average']:
                                            for i in ['long', 'short', 'average']:
                                                for j in [True, False]:
                                                    for k in ['thin', 'thick', 'average']:
                                                        for l in ['thin', 'thick', 'average']:
                                                            yield [x, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l]
    facets_list = list(build_list(xrange(1,121)))
    print len(facets_list)
```

Comment: As soon as I saw it, my eyes bulged and I thought to myself, "yes!"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. You can use [`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
import itertools
facets_list = list(itertools.product(types,
                                    ['short', 'long', 'average'],
                                    ['square', 'sloped', 'average'],
                                    ['small', 'large', 'average'],
                                     ...))
```

Comment: And use `tuple`s instead of `list`s (makes the original version about 12% faster).

Comment: This solution ends up being about twice as fast as the original version, and using `tuple`s instead of `list`s makes it 1-2% faster still (much less of a difference than with the original).

Comment: @Chris, in the original each time a loop begins the list is recreated fresh which explains the large improvement when compared to tuples.

Comment: Yep, it's initialisation which is the overhead. General rule: tuples are better than lists where appropriate and should always be used unless you want to write to them.